# #1143 - SELECT command denied to user 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost' for column 'default_collation_id' in table 'character_sets'

Tags: mysql

I am working on Mac OS right now creating database. I can log into my account but I have this problem

```
Error SQL query: Copy DocumentationEdit Edit


SELECT `CHARACTER_SET_NAME` AS `Charset`, `DEFAULT_COLLATE_NAME` AS `Default collation`, `DESCRIPTION` AS `Description`, `MAXLEN` AS `Maxlen` FROM `information_schema`.`CHARACTER_SETS` MySQL said: Documentation
#1143 - SELECT command denied to user 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost' for column 'default_collation_id' in table 'character_sets'
```

And all my Databases are gone and I can't see them in the left bar. And when I go to SQL folder it says

```
#1356 - View 'information_schema.SCHEMATA' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
```

What should I do?

Comment: login as **root** and check your tables. And see if your backup is uptodate

Comment: @nbk how do you check backup update?

Comment: If everything worked before, i believe that your files a re corrupted, so i hope you made a recent backup of all your data. So that if the check up and restore of your current database fails, you use your backup to have a at least functioning database

Comment: unfortunately I didn't make a back up, but right now I just need to have at least access to creating databases. every time I try to it says : "#1143 - SELECT command denied to user 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost' for column 'default_collation_id' in table ‘character_sets'
"

Comment: and Im logged in but I can't create databases :(

Comment: can't you login as root?

Comment: I am already logged in as root

Comment: Good try to grant privileges to your user

Comment: How to grand privileges ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html and of course there are much more pages that inform about granting privileges to users

Comment: okay I see, I've tried but I don't have rights to grant privileges because I don't have privileges

Comment: check first the privileges of the root account in mysql. It has usually all rights. Maybe you made an error or defines another superuser account, that has all rights.

Comment: I've never made another account. its so confusing, maybe I could've deleted something important from my account by mistake?

Comment: I think install everything new and try again. root has all privileges and he can grant other mysql users all privileges which their need, if this doesn't work something is wrong with your system. If repairing the tables doesn't work. Install everything new.

Comment: okay thank you, ill try! So I have to delete all php files & mysql files from pc and install it all again? like create a new account?

Answer (score 6):

For same problem I just solved this by using this command:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysql.* TO 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command :
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysql.infoschema'@'localhost';